# in kotlin how to check whether the object is instance of a base class or derived class

Tags: inheritance, kotlin

Having a base class and a derived class (simplified here)

```
open class BaseClass {
    var baseData: BaseData? = null
}
open class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
    var drivedData: DerivedData? = null
}
```

And a array for BaseClass

```
val list = ArrayList<BaseClass>()
// populated the list with mixed objects of BaseClass and DerivedClass

for (obj in list) {
    when (obj){
        is DerivedClass -> {}
        is BaseClass -> {}
    }
}
```

This may work because it checked first whether it is DerivedClass then check against BaseClass.

If there is better way without making use of the order of the checking?

Comment: The better way would be to use polymorphism instead of checking the type of the variable.

Comment: @JB Nizet, thx! the problem is those classes are from some 3rd party and it does not provide expected functionality but only some data either in base or derived. Need to check what class in order to get the right data.

Comment: @lannyf you can make wrapper class for BaseClass/DerivedClass object, and map your list to it. So than checking and casting will be incapsulate inside wrapper or maybe factory for this wrapper.

Comment: What is relation between `BaseData` class, `BaseClass`, `DerivedClass` and `DerivedData` classes? I see `DerivedClass` is inherited from `BaseClass `, but what about `BaseData` class? You are iterating the list of `BaseData` objects which, how I see from your code, is not inherited from `BaseClass` class.

Comment: @Sergey, thx! that was a typo and edited.

Comment: For objects in `list`, you only need to check if they are instances of `DerivedClass` because you already know they are instances of `BaseClass` (unless there are shenanigans with type erasure happening).

Answer (score 1):

What about this

```
val list = ArrayList<BaseClass>()

for (obj in list) {
    when(obj.javaClass.name) {
        BaseClass.clazz() -> { println("is base !") }
        DerivedClass.clazz() ->  { println("is derived !") }
    }
}
```

With :

```
open class BaseClass {
    companion object {
        fun clazz() = "BaseClass"
    }
}

open class DerivedClass : BaseClass() {
    companion object {
        fun clazz() = "DerivedClass"
    }
}
```

I know it is not that great, we have to deal with an additional method `clazz()` and we didn't use the `is` operator, but at least it answers the question: *is there a way without making use of the order of the checking :)*

Comment: dont have code access to the BaseClass, sorry cant do with adding function there

Comment: this is not an issue here (if the BaseClass has a companion object), you can add any function to a class using extensions even if you don't have access to it, check this : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html

Comment: that might be an option, thx! But still want to see if there is native "type" support there.